# How can I inform a C++ application with JSON data when an event occurs in my PHP?

Tags: php, c++

Basically, I want to inform a C++ application (a game application) when an event occurs in my PHP page.

Below is an example:

- User logs in to website and purchases something.
- PHP validates this transaction and returns a JSON/XML object to C++ application.
- C++ application receives transactionID and gives user the item he bought.

Right now I do this in a bad way. PHP writes to database, C++ application constantly reads the database, causing a performance loss.

How can I archieve this?

Comment: Um this is pretty broad. You're basically asking for a ten-page design document, and you're not going to get it here. However, for £500/hr, I'll help you out.

Comment: i don't think your current method is particularly 'bad'

Comment: I'll undercut @LightnessRacesinOrbit and do it for £499.50/hr

Comment: Only because you'll have a bigger budget.

Comment: @vascowhite: And because I'm teh awesomer. Though your website is pretty good.

Comment: "C++ application constantly reads the database" about what time intervals are you talking? Busy wait or every 2 Minutes?

Comment: @nohero; Something like 5 seconds.

Comment: Polling every 5 seconds seems reasonable enough. Direct comms may or may not be worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) supports both PHP and C++;

Simple hello World Example

```
//
//  Hello World server in C++
//  Binds REP socket to tcp://*:5555
//  Expects "Hello" from client, replies with "World"
//
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main () {
    //  Prepare our context and socket
    zmq::context_t context (1);
    zmq::socket_t socket (context, ZMQ_REP);
    socket.bind ("tcp://*:5555");

    while (true) {
        zmq::message_t request;

        //  Wait for next request from client
        socket.recv (&request);
        std::cout << "Received Hello" << std::endl;

        //  Do some 'work'
        sleep (1);

        //  Send reply back to client
        zmq::message_t reply (5);
        memcpy ((void *) reply.data (), "World", 5);
        socket.send (reply);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

PHP

```
$context = new ZMQContext();
$requester = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_REQ);
$requester->connect("tcp://localhost:5555");

//Send Simple Request
$requester->send("Hello");

//Get Response Form C++
printf("Received reply %s", $requester->recv());
```

Comment: Were looking for something like this, thanks alot. Knew it could be done in a way without feeding trolls with 500£ per hour.

Comment: You might have to pay 500£ per hour to Lightness Races in Orbit if you really want a scalable system

Comment: I rather pay 500£ per hour for a decent cluster server which just works for this purpose. I bet it'll outscale whatever he can archieve.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of solving the problem. You might create a simple service listening on C++. 
Whenever a new order is handled in PHP, it should inform the Service of C++

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a good choice of [interprocess communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).  If it's on a single system then sockets are a common choice.  The the applications are on separate systems then it depends on some of your requirements.