# Combining PHP and C++ programing

Tags: php, c++, web-services, web-applications

Hey guys I am thinking of trying to combine C++ network programing with PHP I have knowledge in PHP/MySQL/AJAX and etc but haven't got much in C++. SO I am thinking of building A web apps. And making clients for them using Cpp/Qt4 as example:

```
The php app is a chat application/server that offers the users to chat in rooms or PMs and etc. ( Like IRC ).
And would want to make a chat client in Cpp/Qt4 to be downloadable and use the same server. Like (mIRC)
```

- Should I use PHP as a server or I should reconsider another language?
- Is Qt4 a good suggestion or I have to reconsider?
- How should I connect PHP to C++ ?

I would like to help me with some techniques or resources that I should refer to.
Thank you in advance!
Cheers!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13258230/1226894

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest you look into developing a SaaS based application using PHP, Ruby, Node or any other serverside language you prefer..

In this way, you'll only have to worry about creating the interface in c++ and interacting with the API you've created. Connections to the database and other requests will be done over the server

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that mixing Qt with PHP is a good idea. PHP is a (quite poor) programming language for Web servers (you could consider [Opa](http://opalang.org/), or Ocaml with [Ocsigen](http://ocsigen.org/), or even C++ with [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt)).

Qt is running on the desktop usually. (So running a Qt program from a PHP one requires the web server to have access to your desktop's [X11 server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System), which is unusual).

You could have some Web service running, e.g. thru FastCGI, and mix them with your PHP thing. For instance, you could have an Ajax `XMLHttpRequest` inside your PHP application querying a FastCGI or CGI written in C++.

Comment: I do not want php to run a Qt client I want to make everithing as a web app. Like to say a Chat room and give the option to the users to download a C++ Qt4 client to use it instead of staying in the browse.( Just a example.).

Comment: But then you have two different applications (one in the web browser & the web server, another in Qt & perhaps some server), perhaps communicating thru a protocol. Don't think of them as a single application.